# How to display image with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image, object

I am trying to display image, through JavaScript, but i can't figure out how to do that. I have following

```
function image(a,b,c)
{
  this.link=a;
  this.alt=b;
  this.thumb=c;
}

function show_image()
{
  document.write("img src="+this.link+">");
}

image1=new image("img/img1.jpg","dsfdsfdsfds","thumb/img3");
```

in HTML

```
<p><input type="button" value="Vytvor" onclick="show_image()" > </p>
```

I can't figure out where should I put something like `image1.show_image();`.

HTML? Or somewhere else...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You could make use of the [Javascript DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference/Introduction#What_is_the_DOM.3F). In particular, look at the [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement) method.

You could create a re-usable function that will create an image like so...

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;

    // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```

Then you could use it like this...

```
<button onclick=
    "show_image('http://google.com/images/logo.gif', 
                 276, 
                 110, 
                 'Google Logo');">Add Google Logo</button>
```

### See a working example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/

Comment: The fiddle shows a button with the name 'Add Google Logo'. When pressed, the text 'Google Logo' is added to the right. No image is visible. I checked the existence of the logo.gif image & got a 404 error. When I changed it to an existing address (https://www.pinterest.at/pin/340655159306311689/), it did the same again. Tested with Google Chrome version 60.0.3112.113 (official build) (64-bit)

Comment: You are correct @Sae1962 when I wrote this over 6 years ago I sort of knew that at some point the url would probably return 404

Comment: :-D The problem is not with you, but with stackoverflow that does not has a coherent page that includes ALL stuff about a question but relies on other pages.

Comment: Thankfully in this situation it's pretty easy to "get" the concept even if the image is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you... I made small modifications/simplifications. Works as intended.

HTML:
Add Image

Javascript:

function addLogo() {
var src = "https://i.gifer.com/origin/93/935d72c7bc35828ea93b5898691f28fd_w200.gif";
show_image(src, 124,124, "My Image");
}

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = src;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
    img.alt = alt;
    document.body.appendChild(img);
}
```