# Assign image to random number-range

Tags: javascript

So, I've got my code ready to generate and print a random number between "-20 and 20".

What I'd like to do, and this is where I'm stuck, is to assign 4 different images to a number range between my total range of "-20 to 20".

For instance:

- `image1.gif` would be assigned to any random # between "-20 and -10"
- `image2.gif` assigned to "-9 and 0"
- `image3.gif` to "1 and 10"
- `image4.gif` to "11 and 20"

Any suggestions much welcomed!

EDIT:
So based on Jon's answer, i've changed the last two lines to a document.write and am trying to get my actual images shown above the text output. I'm however aware of a faulty line in the IMG.SRC. What would this be needed to change to if my images were lying in my root dir? Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<title>RANDOM IMAGE TO NUMBER RANGE</title>
<body>
<center>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var ranges = [
    { from: 11, image: "image4.jpg" },
    { from: 1, image: "image3.jpg" },
    { from: -9, image: "image2.jpg" },
    { from: -20, image: "image1.jpg" }       
];

var random_num = (Math.round((Math.random()*41)+-20));
var image = "default";

for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; ++i) {
    if(random_num >= ranges[i].from) {
        image = ranges[i].image;
        break;
    }
}
document.write("Number: " + random_num + " parts, " + " Imagetitle: = " + image);
document.write('<img src="'+ranges[image]+'">');

</script>
<br></br>
<div>
CLICK <a href="javascript:history.go(0);">REFRESH or F5</a> FOR A RANDOM IMAGE on NUMBER-RANGE.
</div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by assigning an image to a random number (i.e. how should they be linked)? It seems you'd have to change your formula to four different ones to generate numbers in the four ranges you describe.

Comment: What about generating a number between 1 und 4 as all those intervals have the same size?

Comment: How about you divide your number between -20 and 20 by 10 and then add 2? (Or add 20 and then divide by 10.)

Comment: The first interval seems to be one bigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the ranges inside an array and iterate over it to find which range you are in:

```
// IMPORTANT: array is sorted in descending "from" order!
var ranges = [
    { from: 11, image: "image4" },
    { from: 1, image: "image3" },
    { from: -9, image: "image2" },
    { from: -20, image: "image1" }       
];

var random_num = (Math.round((Math.random()*41)+-20));
var image = "default";

for(var i = 0; i < ranges.length; ++i) {
    if(random_num >= ranges[i].from) {
        image = ranges[i].image;
        break;
    }
}

alert("random_num = " + random_num + " / image = " + image);
```

This will work correctly for intervals that may or may not be equal, and can easily be adapted to slightly more complex interval definitions.

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/3x4Hd/)**.

Comment: Thanks alot everyone for your input! I found this specific code to be working for me spot on. How would I go about trying to change the alert popup to the showing of the actual images in the root dir though? i.e: "document.write('<IMG SRC="+images' +ranges[image]+ '">');"

Comment: @fizd: Something like `"images/" + ranges[i].image` for the path to the file. You should also use another method than `document.write` to show the image; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function below 4 times with parameters (-20, -11), (-10, -1), (0, 9), (10, 19).

```
function get_rand_int(min, max) {

    return Math.floor(min + Math.random() * (max - min + 1));

} // get_rand_int()
```