# How to make images appear in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, gallery

I'm not very fluent in javascript, and I feel like this is really basic, but I can't seem to find it online **anywhere**.

I want to create a link that will trigger a javascript function that makes an image appear in a separate div.  It can't be in flash, otherwise I have no objection to the coding language.

I have several images, so I would think that the best way to do this would be to layer them all on top of each other and then increase the z-index each time their link is clicked, but you might have a better idea.

I really just want someway to create a sort of primitive image gallery that doesn't use flash and displays the photo in its div when the corresponding link is clicked.

Thanks in advance, Alex

Comment: can you create a small, demonstrable example of what you have done so far?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript/5454306#5454306

Answer (score 1):

As Jessegavin said (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5454306/1406409))

You could make use of the Javascript DOM API. In particular, look at
the createElement() method.

You could create a re-usable function that will create an image like
so...

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = src;
  img.width = width;
  img.height = height;
  img.alt = alt;
  
  // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
  document.body.appendChild(img); 
}
```

Then you could use it like this...

```
<button onclick="show_image('http://google.com/images/logo.gif', 
  276,110, 'Google Logo");'>Add Google Logo</button>
```

There shouldn't be a line break above, I added it so that it could
show without scrolling See a working example on jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bc6Et/

This should answer your question

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of javascript libraries, plugins (for jQuery) and other ways of solving this problem.

First thing I would do is to peruse a website like this, to see what's available: http://sixrevisions.com/javascript/free_javascript_image_galleries/

I have used this one before, and it's pretty straight forward: http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

In general though you can just do `<a href="javascript: showImage()">Link</a>` and clicking that will call the javascript function `showImage()` that you define somewhere.  Then layering the divs will work as you have described.