# Using Javascript how can I display an image if the value of 2 fields are equal?

Tags: javascript

I have a form that I want to be able to compare the numbers entered in two input boxes and if they match then I want to display a thumbs up image if they don't I want to display a thumbs down image. I'm attempting to use javascript to do this but I'm not sure how to get the images to display. I've searched this topic but am unable to find anything that explains how to display an image using javascript in the manner I need to do it. 
Here is what I have for my code so far, and I'm not even sure if what I have is even correct,

```
if document.getElementById("scan_out").value == document.getElementById("scan_in").value 
//do something here to display thumbs_up.png
else document.getElementById("scan_out").value >= document.getElementById("scan_in").value
//do something here to display thumbs_down.png
```

This is my first attempt at javascript so I'm not sure if I'm on the right track or not?

so this is what I have now as given from answers below

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="firstField"/>
        <img src="images/thumbs_up.png" style="display: none;" id="image1"/>
        <img src="images/thumbs_down.png" style="display:block;" id=image2"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="secField" onchange="equals()"/>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstField = document.getElementById('firstField');
    var secField =   document.getElementById('secField');
    var image =    document.getElementById('image2');
    var image =    document.getElementById('image1');

    function equals() {
        if(firstField.value == secField.value) {
            image.style.display = 'block';
        }
        else {
            image.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
firstField.onkeyup = function() { equals() }
    secField.onkeyup = function() { equals() }


</script>
```

but this always displays a thumbs down image then adds the thumbs up image if the inputs match showing both the thumbs up and thumbs down. I don't want there to be an image unless the values match or don't match but only after a value is input.

Comment: Is this all the you've tried?

Comment: I believe your question may be answered in this thread:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554273/changing-the-image-source-using-jquery

Comment: @Pablo208 I've read that thread already and it doesn't answer my question

Comment: This will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya Thanks but that doesn't help, I've look at all the suggestions for answers already given on stackoverflow but none of them give a clear answer as to how I can display the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clean and easy way with js is following...

**after edit**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="firstField"/>
        <img src="images/thumbs_up.png" style="display: none; background: #000;" id="image"/>
        <img src="images/thumbs_down.png" style="display: none; background: #ff0000;" id="image2"/>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="secField" onchange="equals()"/>
    </form>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var firstField = document.getElementById('firstField');
    var secField =   document.getElementById('secField');
    var image =    document.getElementById('image');
    var image2 =    document.getElementById('image2');

    function equals() {
        if(firstField.value == secField.value) {
            image.style.display = 'block';
            image2.style.display = 'none';
        }
        else {
            image.style.display = 'none';
            image2.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
    firstField.onkeyup = equals;
    secField.onkeyup = equals;


</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you wrap `equals()` in an anonymous function? Just do `firstField.onkeyup = equals;` and also use `addEventListener`.

Comment: thank you :)

can you tell me more about `addEventListener` or give me some link about it??

Comment: @maxART Thank you this helps a lot on getting the image to display, just need to work out some stuff like not having the image display until the values are compared.

Comment: @maxART Thanks I appreciate the effort but it's still the same, when the page loads it shows thumbs down and when I add the equal values to each box it displays a thumbs up along with the thumbs down. I can't figure out how to remove the thumbs down from the initial loading of the page.

Comment: @maxART correction to the above, noticed too late to edit but your changes do in fact work, it only displays the one image now on equal values, just need to figure out how to stop the thumbs down from displaying after a value is entered in the first box but I think removing the onkeyup from the first box will do that. Thank you fro your help

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty `div` with id `img1` and use this code

```
if( document.getElementById("scan_out").value == document.getElementById("scan_in").value)

{ 
     document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML='<img src="path/to/image.png">';
}
    else if( document.getElementById("scan_out").value >= document.getElementById("scan_in").value){
    document.getElementById("img1").innerHTML='<img src="path/to/image2.png">';
}
```

Comment: simple, but effective.

Comment: Why did you copy the pseudo code from OP's post? This is not working. Even if you would make this JS, it would always show "thumbdown" or nothing changes.

Comment: Well the poster didnt really give us alot to work with. This answer purely how to show and image with javascripts like the poster asked right?

Comment: `innerHTML` is not a function, but a property, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(document.getElementById("scan_out").value == document.getElementById("scan_in").value){
     document.getElementById("img_id").src= "images/xyz/someimage.png";
    }
    else if(document.getElementById("scan_out").value == document.getElementById("scan_in").value){
   document.getElementById("img_id1").src= "images/xyz/someimage.png";
}
```

Comment: The same lack of logic here... "`if they match then ... thumbs up ... if they don't ... thumbs down`".

Comment: I have tested it and it has workde..can you point out where i am going wrong?i will delete my answer if your answer is valid...are you talking about replacing div with images or images with images??

Comment: First checking == , then >= makes this funny. Sorry for the markup, I'm on a phone now, a thunder storm just arrived here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how can you match numbers.

```
var n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('text1').value, 10);
var n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('text2').value, 10);
var l = document.querySelector('label');
if (n1 == n2)
    l.innerHTML = 'Number1 = Number2';
else
    l.innerHTML = 'Number1 != Number2';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to JavaScript, you shall definitely use jQuery.

Then the code would be:

```
if ( $("#scan_out").val() === $("#scan_in").val() ) {
   $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="thumbs_up.png">');
} else {
   $("#scan_icon").html('<img src="thumbs_down.png">');
}
```

You should place `<div id="scan_icon"></div>` where you want the icon to appear.

Comment: If you're new to JavaScript, you definitely _should not_ use jQuery. Not my downvote though.

Comment: @Richard I tried this but it didn't work, I added the code just as you have it and placed the div where I want the image to display but nothing happens when I enter values in the input boxes

Comment: @user594112 You must have done some mistake, it works, look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cqHtF/

Comment: @Teemu: Why not? When properly taught, it allows you to write much cleaner code than pure JS. Please explain your objection, I'm really interested in your opinion.

Comment: When you are learning the basics of JS and especially DOM, you will get a better understanding how all works, when using pure JS. We can see the consequences of starting with jQuery even here at SO. When a programmer knowing only jQuery gets a job, which must be done without jQuery, we answer here questions like: Why my getElementById is not working? `var a = document.getElementById('#foo');`