# Displaying Images in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, image, web

OK, so I'm making a website in HTML, and it's working great, but I need to know how to display images on the page in javascript. I have in my website where there is a part on the homepage called news, and it's going to display an image about the topic, but I don't know how to display the image. When I use other website's ways, the image just displays as a square with a ? in the middle. Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1jyw3shk/)

**javascript:**

```
var i = document.getElementById('test'); //get the element to put the picture in 

i.innerHTML = '<img src="http://pathtopicture.jpg"></img>'; // append the picture to the divs inner HTML
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

---

**Or without HTML in the first place** (of course you need html and body tag...)

**[DEMO2](http://jsfiddle.net/1jyw3shk/1/)**

Code:

```
var i = document.createElement('div');
i.id = 'test';
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(i);
i.innerHTML = '<img src="http://pathtopicture.jpg"></img>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = src;
img.width = width;
img.height = height;
img.alt = alt;

var theDiv = document.getElementById("<ID_OF_THE_DIV>");
theDiv.appendChild(content);
```

I got these answers from:
[How to display image with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript)
[How to append data to div using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)