# How to add an image with an if statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a way to have an image appear when a certain phrase is typed into an input using an if statement?  This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {

        var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase(); ;
        if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {

            document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters";

        } else if (ask== "how tall is the gateway arch") {

            document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "630 feet";

        }
```

Comment: Yes it's possible - and your code looks alright - what's the question? How to append the image?

Comment: You can use base64 image as IMG SRC, google it

Comment: Along with words appearing I want there to be an image along with it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like -

```
document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "<img src='path/arch.jpg'>";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "<p>630 feet</p><img src='path/gatewayarch.jpg'>";
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is set the image's path - this will load the image off the web server:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("button").onclick=function() {

    var imageSrc = "";

    var ask=document.getElementById("ask").value.toLowerCase(); ;
    if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {
        document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters";
        imageSrc = "pyramids.jpg";
    } else if (ask== "how tall is the gateway arch") {
        document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "630 feet";
        imageSrc = "arch.jpg";
    }

    // update the image
    document.getElementById("image_placeholder").src = imageSrc;
```

You can also "preload" all the images so that the UI feels snappier. To do so you can create `Image` objects in a loop and set their `.src` to the images' paths. Once they are loaded the image flip will be immediate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some ways of achieving what you want, e.g:

```
if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {
  document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = "146.5 meters <img src='yourimg.png'>";
```

Or:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');

if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {
  var span = document.getElementById("spanId");
  span.innerHTML = "146.5 meters";
  img.src = 'yourimg.png';
  span.appendChild(img);
```

Or, if you don't have the image located physically in your webserver, you can do:

```
if (ask =="how tall are the pyramids") {
  var base64 = 'YOUR_IMAGE_BASE64_STRING';
  document.getElementById("spanId").innerHTML = '146.5 meters <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,' + base64 + '" />';
```

You can convert any image you have to a base64 string with [this converter](https://www.base64-image.de/).