# display images array onclick button

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick

HTML: I set the button onclick "myFunction" Now I would like images to be displayed onclick

```
<body>



<p>Click the button to see some images</p>


<button onclick="myFunction()">See the Images!!!</button>



<script src="js2/images.js">





</script>

</body>
```

JS: Need to display images onclick...Not sure if i am on the right track as I am a beginner at JS...I cant seem to get the images to display, only the src name of the images....

```
function myFunction() {

pge = new Array ()

 pge[4] = "../images/sky3.jpg"


 pge[3] = "../images/sky8.jpg"

 pge[2] = "../images/sky7.jpg"

 pge[5] = "../images/sky6.jpg"

 pge[0] = "../images/sky5.jpg"

 pge[1]= "../images/sky4.jpg"

 pge[6] = "../images/sky1.jpg"  

 pge[7] = "../images/sky2.jpg"




 for (i=0;i<=pge.length-1;i++) {


var img = document.createElement("img");
```

????????

```
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add line

```
img.setAttribute("src", pge[i]);
```

in your ?????? part

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick. (in part based on [How to display image with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript))

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body> 
 <p>Click the button to see some images</p>

 <button onclick="myFunction()">See the Images!!!</button>

 <script>
  function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
   var img = document.createElement("img");
   img.src = src;
   img.width = width;
   img.height = height;
   img.alt = alt;

   // This next line will just add it to the <body> tag
   document.body.appendChild(img);
  }
   
  function myFunction() {
   var pge = ["http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/pic_the_scream.jpg", "http://www.w3schools.com/images/colorpicker.gif"];

   for(var i = 0; i < pge.length; i++){
    show_image(pge[i], 100, 200, i)
   }
  }          
 </script>
</body>
</html
```

Comment: Nice! so that works when I use the images from w3schools, however when I try and use the images I have in a folder on my computer it does not display the images just the "alt"???? do I need to change the src???

Comment: Use the folder/location relative to your path where your index.html is e.g. images/sky1.jpg instead of those two examples I put there in the array. Like var pge = ["images/sky1.jpg", "images/sky2.jpg", "images/sky3.jpg", ...]

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML needs a place to display the images when the button is clicked. You can use CSS to style the div.

```
<body>
        <p>Click the button to see some images</p>

        <button onclick="myFunction()">See the Images!!!</button>

        <div id="showImg"></div>        

        <script src="js2/images.js"></script>    
</body>
```

You don’t have to use the Array constructor. Store your images in an array as shown below, use a for-loop to loop through the array, then use the innerHTML property to create img tags, locate your images and display them. You can use CSS to style the images.

```
    var pge = ["sky3.jpg", "sky8.jpg", "sky7.jpg", "sky6.jpg", "sky5.jpg", "sky4.jpg", "sky1.jpg", "sky2.jpg"];
var showImg = document.getElementById("showImg");

var myFunction = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < pge.length; i++)
    {
        showImg.innerHTML = "<img src='images/" + pge[0] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[1] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[2] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[3] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[4] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[5] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[6] + "'/> <img src='images/" + pge[7] + "'/>";
    }
}
```