# Make the bot post random images

Tags: javascript, discord

Hey I am creating a bot atm. What I wanna do is by writing a command make the bot post random images that are saved in my pc. What's the command for that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript) should help you. To select a random image, I'd give the images values and use a simple RNG `Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);` (1-10 here or however many images you have) to select the image. 
Hope that helped!

Comment: I know about the math and name the images a number so it selects them randomly, but I want all that to be asigned to a command, What I dont know is how to code something like that. Don't you have the code or know a little bit about it?

Comment: @PauloCosta I think this answer is quite appropriate given that your question shows no effort on your part.