# how to change image link in "a" tag to <img>

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, tags

One of the WordPress plugins renders the uploaded image as a link:

```html
<a href="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" target="_blank" aria-label="new">news-paper.png</a>
```

I want to convert it to an  tag with JavaScript so that the link is displayed as an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not super familiar w/ Wordpress so there may be an easier way, but you could convert that link into an image by...

- Changing the <a ... tag to an <image ... tag :

```html
<image src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" target="_blank" aria-label="new"/>
```

- adding an image via JS based off that value

```js
    function add_google_logo() {     show_image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png", 276,110, "Google Logo");
    }


    function show_image(src, width, height, alt) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
```

```html
<button onclick="add_google_logo();">Add Google Logo</button>
```

^ completely ripped from this post: [How to display image with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451445/how-to-display-image-with-javascript)